# JUnit 4 tests results not showing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

My problem is that JUnit 4 test results are not showing in Eclipse.
I have added System.out.println("....") to each of @Test methods in my test class and they ran cause Console shows the output, however, the JUnit tab next to my package explorer is not showing any results. It says runs 0/0, errors 0, failures 0.

I should add that I have added JUnit 4 to build path.
I browsed the internet in search of an answer for like an hour and didn't find anything. What is the problem here? I would really appreciate any clue!

Comment: Silly things, but make sure the following is true: you are running the tests *inside* Eclipse as JUnit tests, test runs are not accidentally being added to JUnit history w/o being shown in the screen. Also, do you have any relevant errors in your error log? Paste them in your question.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for replying so quickly.
Yes, I am running them inside eclipse as JUnit tests, there are no errors and yes, the test are being added to history. How can I change where the results go?

Comment: Does it still work in a project with JUnit 3?
Did you try to create a new run configuration for your test? Maybe something went wrong in the config.

Comment: @Bastian JUnit isn't working either... I tried different run configurations, to a reasonable extent. Do you have something specific on mind?

Comment: Not sure whats broken. Did you give the JUnit preferences page a try? Following option might be worth trying: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> JUnit | Show newly launched test in all JUnit views

Comment: @Bastian I marked both "Add -ea to VM arguments...." and "Show newly launched test in all JUnit views" and reran the test. No effect :/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while working with **Spring Boot 2.5.1**

Essentially, starting with Spring Boot 2.4, JUnit 5's vintage engine has been removed from `spring-boot-starter-test`. If we still want to write tests using JUnit 4, we need to add the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I try everything , but still fail to shown junit4 result  in Eclipse, but I think maybe this problem is eclipse bug.  My environments is Mac OS 11x EI and Eclipse Mars for 64 mac, and JDK is 1.7
  I use the same Eclipse Mars (for windows x86) in my pc , it's OK. so I can think only may be is  a environment's problem.

At last, I try jdk 1.6 + eclipse luna for mac(32),it's work!!, so you can try other eclipse version.