# JUnit 4 tests results not showing in Eclipse?

Tags: junit4

My problem is that JUnit 4 test results are not showing in Eclipse. I have added System.out.println("....") to each of @Test methods in my test class and they ran cause Console shows the output, however, the JUnit tab next to my package explorer is not showing any results. It says runs 0/0, errors 0, failures 0.

I should add that I have added JUnit 4 to build path. I browsed the internet in search of an answer for like an hour and didn't find anything. What is the problem here? I would really appreciate any clue!

Comment: how are you executing the tests from within eclipse? perhaps you are running them from the command line? is it a maven/gradle java app?

Comment: i am having the same problem. it just started. jdk 16 eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639. tried the -ea and other idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738490/junit-4-tests-results-not-showing-in-eclipse. no joy. only failed tests are showing. how to turn this off so they all show?

Comment: only failed tests are showing. how to turn this off so they all show? found it - small icon that says show failures only.